# Implement multivariate normal pdf in c++ for image classification

Tags: c++, boost, classification, normal-distribution, probability-density

I am looking to implement the multivariate normal PDF [ [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Density_function) ] in C++ to assign each pixel in an image membership of a class, i.e.

```
    for each pixel
        for each class
            compute multivariate normal PDF using the pixel's feature vector and the class' mean vector and covariance matrix
         end
     end
```

Is there a library that can do this in an efficient manner (i.e. similar to Matlab's mvnpdf function[[2](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/mvnpdf.html)])? If not any ideas what libraries or approaches would be best (I was thinking of using Eigen).

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a ready-to-go one-step solution. For a two-step mix-and-match approach, you could familiarize yourself with [Boost.Math](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/html/index.html) which has an [extended example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/stat_tut/weg/normal_example/normal_misc.html) for the **univariate** normal distrubtion in the statistical distribution section:

```
// [...] many headers and namespaces inclusions

int main()
{
      // Construct a standard normal distribution s
        normal s; // (default mean = zero, and standard deviation = unity)
        cout << "Standard normal distribution, mean = "<< s.mean()
          << ", standard deviation = " << s.standard_deviation() << endl;

/*` First the probability distribution function (pdf).
*/
      cout << "Probability distribution function values" << endl;
      cout << "  z " "      pdf " << endl;
      cout.precision(5);
      for (double z = -range; z < range + step; z += step)
      {
        cout << left << setprecision(3) << setw(6) << z << " " 
          << setprecision(precision) << setw(12) << pdf(s, z) << endl;
      }
      cout.precision(6); // default

      // [...] much more
    }
```

You could then use Eigen to do the necessary vector and matrix manipulation to pass a scalar to that. This [blog posting](http://lost-found-wandering.blogspot.nl/2011/05/sampling-from-multivariate-normal-in-c.html) has more details (although it uses [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) to generate the sample values).